# Installed SDK but no wearable templates show up

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm following the instructions at https://developer.tizen.org/development/getting-started/web-application/creating-your-first-tizen-application#wearapp to use the Tizen SDK to create a wearable "hello, world" app. However the wearable project templates do not appear.

I have done the full SDK installation with all extensions twice. I still cannot get the wearable templates to appear as shown on that "getting started" page.

How does one properly install the SDK including wearable templates?

Answer (score 3):

I found out on the Tizen SDK forum that the 2.4 version of the SDK does not (yet?) support wearables -- it's mobile only. It's confusing because Samsung's page shows 2.4 wearable profiles, but they are not available. I installed the 2.3.1 version of the SDK and I do see wearable profiles.